# ¿Por qué el for repite dos veces su contenido?

Tags: php, json, bucle-for

Mi **for** en PHP repite 2 veces el contenido, y no entiendo por qué.

He intentado asignando nuevas variables únicas, agregando un `unset($friends);` al final del for, para *limpiarlo*, pero sigue repitiendo dos veces el valor $friends.

¿Cómo podría hacer que no se repita?

---

users.json

```
{
  "user": [
    {
      "name": "user1",
      "friends": [
        "Friend1",
        "Friend2",
        "Friend3"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "user2",
      "friends": [
        "Friend4",
        "Friend5"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Código en PHP

```
<?php 
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("users.json"),true);

for($i = 0; $i <= count($data["user"]) -1; $i++){
    $user_name = $data["user"][$i]["name"];

    $friends = "";
    for($f = 0; $f <= count($data["user"][$i]["friends"]) -1; $f++){
         $friends .=  $data["user"][$i]["friends"][$f] . ", ";
    }
    $friends .=  substr($friends,0,-2);
    
    echo "Los amigos de " . $user_name . " son " . $friends . "<br/>";
}
```

output del código actual:

```
    Los amigos de user1 son Friend1, Friend2, Friend3, Friend1, Friend2, Friend3
    Los amigos de user2 son Friend4, Friend5, Friend4, Friend5
```

output deseado:

```
    Los amigos de user1 son Friend1, Friend2, Friend3
    Los amigos de user2 son Friend4, Friend5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es necesario hacer un ciclo para obtener los amigos, basta con usar [`implode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php) para unirlos:

```
<?php

$data = json_decode('{
  "user": [
    {
      "name": "user1",
      "friends": [
        "Friend1",
        "Friend2",
        "Friend3"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "user2",
      "friends": [
        "Friend4",
        "Friend5"
      ]
    }
  ]
}');

foreach($data->user as $user) {
    echo "Los amigos de {$user->name} son:" . implode(', ', $user->friends) . '<br>';
}
```

Resultado:

```
Los amigos de user1 son:Friend1, Friend2, Friend3
Los amigos de user2 son:Friend4, Friend5
```

Answer (score 4):

Tengo entendido que el operador .= agrega el valor al valor inicial, no lo reemplaza, por eso te sale doble.
El operador fuera del for que está duplicando su mismo valor. Este: $friends .= substr($friends,0,-2)

Comment: Claro, pero lo que hago ahí, es agregarle al $friends "Friend1, ", luego "Friend2, " y por ultimo "Friend3, ".
Pero repite esa acción 2 veces.

Comment: Me refiero al operador fuera del for, creo que está duplicando su mismo valor.  Este: $friends .=  substr($friends,0,-2)

Comment: ohhhh, tienes razón, jajaja no me había percatado, ¡gracias!

Comment: @AngelReynaTorrejon, esta respuesta sería correcta si lo que has comentado estuviera en la respuesta. Los comentarios son temporales. ¿Podrías [edit] la respuesta y agregar lo que has comentado?